# After upgrade the system to 15.04 the LibreOffice does not wan't to start

Tags: updates, libreoffice, 15.04

After upgrade the system from 14.10 to 15.04 the LibreOffice ( calc / writer ) does not wan't to start. 
I get : LibreOffice 4.4 - Fatal Error  The application cannot be started. User installation could not be completed.

Comment: can you run libreoffice from terminal and provide us console output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to delete `~/.config/libreoffice`

```
rm ~/.config/libreoffice
```

and restart LibreOffice

Comment: THis fixed my problem

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

Open a terminal by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

Run the following commands:

```
sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get --purge remove libreoffice*
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
apt-get install --reinstall deborphan
deborphan
apt-get --purge remove `deborphan`
deborphan –-libdevel
apt-get --purge remove `deborphan --libdevel`
dpkg --purge `COLUMNS=300 dpkg -l | egrep "^rc" | cut -d' ' -f3`

OLDCONF=$(dpkg -l|grep "^rc"|awk '{print $2}')

CURKERNEL=$(uname -r|sed 's/-*[a-z]//g'|sed 's/-386//g')

LINUXPKG="linux-(image|headers|ubuntu-modules|restricted-modules)"

METALINUXPKG="linux-(image|headers|restricted-modules)-(generic|i386|server|common|rt|xen)"

OLDKERNELS=$(dpkg -l|awk '{print $2}'|grep -E $LINUXPKG |grep -vE $METALINUXPKG|grep -v $CURKERNEL)

apt-get purge $OLDCONF
apt-get purge $OLDKERNELS
apt-get install --reinstall libreoffice libreoffice-base-drivers libreoffice-pdfimport libreoffice-help-en-us libreoffice-templates mythes-en-us libreoffice-java-common myspell-en-us libreoffice-common
```